# Profiling Django webserver for high startup times

Tags: django, performance, profiling, webserver, startup

I noted that `manage.py runserver` takes a lot of time to start the development web server for a Django project I'm working on. I'm wondering if there's a way to understand what part of the startup requires so much resources, being eventually able to collect enough information to fix the problem.

Anyone has an idea about what could I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script this may give you a starting point for profiling runserver. However, runserver reloads files when they're edited so generally I find I only need to start it once or twice a day.

Comment: Sorry, my question is not accurate. I missed to explicitly say that the same performance problem also verifies when reloading file (but after all, doesn't "reload file" mean restart the web server? Thenks for the link.

Comment: Can't you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295799/how-to-improve-performance-of-this-code/4299378#4299378)? It's [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

Comment: While using Vagrant, move `virtualenv` folder away from `/vagrant`. See [my answer for similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27997903/1993670).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found an easy and effective solution doing this:

```
python -m cProfile manage.py runserver > profiled
```

Further details about Python profilers [here](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) (official docs).

I'd also post a link to a [video introduction to Python profiling](http://us.pycon.org/2009/conference/schedule/event/15/) and related tools (PyCon 2009)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Could you share what was it that's causing your project to load longer even in local?